# Как сделать вертикальный separator в menu в tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Я хочу вставить вертикальный separator поперёк все пунктов[image: введите сюда описание изображения], но не могу найти способа как это сделать. На картинке показан вертикальный сепаратор, который мне нужен.

```
from tkinter import*
root=Tk()

king=Menu(root)
root.config(menu=king)
#первый пункт меню
file = Menu(king,tearoff = 0)
file.add_command(label='New',accelerator='          CTRL+N')
file.add_command(label='Open',accelerator='          CTRL+O')
file.add_command(label='Save',accelerator='          CTRL+S')
file.add_command(label='Save as')
file.add_separator()
file.add_command(label='Exit')
king.add_cascade(label="File",menu=file)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51564081/tkinter-menu-bar-vertical-dot-separator

Answer (score 1):

Если Вы хотите сделать это в строке меню, вы можете создать команду ничего не делать с изображением или символом Unicode.

```
menubar.add_command(label="\u22EE",
                    activebackground=menubar.cget("background"))
```